# How to reference an icons in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

I am using some icons from this [web site](http://thenounproject.com/). These Icons have such an [attribution](http://thenounproject.com/term/sound-wave/24728/).

How can I reference such an icon in `BibTeX`?

Comment: In the bibliography? Why should you? If you need to state attribution, add a final note to the introduction or somewhere else.

Comment: could you give me an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [“How to attribute” page](http://thenounproject.com/term/sound-wave/24728/) says

> **Books**
>   The attribution should be displayed either on the same page as the symbol, with the colophon, in the bibliography or Credits section.

So you can simply add a “Credits” section at the end of the introduction, or anywhere else, for instance in a final colophon:

```
\section*{Credits}

The icon SoundWave <picture> is designed by 
Aleksandr Novolokov from the Noun Project, under a 
Creative Commons license (CC BY 3.0)
```

Add the other icons you use in the same fashion. In my opinion such attributions are not bibliographic data.